# Add on a included navbar an active tab

Tags: javascript, html

I have a navbar, that i included

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Surveys</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">    
                    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                    <a href="profile.php">Edit Profile</a>
                </li>
                    <?php $url = "viewprofile.php?UserID=" . $_SESSION['UserID']; ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" . $_>Show Profile</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="logout.php">
                        Logout
                    <?php
                        if (!empty($user)) {
                            echo $user['username'];
                        }
                    ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
 </nav>
```

Now i included it in my documents with `<?php include '/navbar.php' ?>`, how i get the Active tab on every site i go, i tried it with the site name, but it dosn't work.
Where i need to put the Script in, in the Navbar file or in the files i included it?
Anyone have a example js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get **QUERY_STRING** From Url

```
<?php $current_page = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); ?>



   <li class="<?php echo ($current_page=='profile.php') ? "active" : '';?>">
      <a href="profile.php">Home</a>
   </li>
<li class="<?php echo ($current_page=='index.php') ? "active" : '';?>">
      <a href="index.php">Home</a>
   </li>


.active{
background-color:#XXXX;
color:#XXXX;
}
```

Comment: Now i get a error, its on the <?php echo (isset($current_page=='profile.php')) ? "active" : '';?>"> 
Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Umfrage\php\navbar.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

Php's include works as a copy/paste.
So your script has to be include in your main HTML document :)